# StageText - How to use more than 1 StageText field?

Tags: mobile, air, flash-cs6

I'm using Flash CS 6 and Air 3.6 to build an Android app. 
I would like to use [StageText](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/StageText.html) for the input fields.
The code below is only working for the first textfield. What do I need change to make it work for both text fields?

```
// NO. 1
var firstfield:StageText = new StageText(); 
firstfield.softKeyboardType = SoftKeyboardType.DEFAULT
firstfield.stage = foobar.stage
firstfield.viewPort = new Rectangle(foobar.x, foobar.y, foobar.width, foobar.height); 

// NO. 2
var secondfield:StageText = new StageText(); 
secondfield.softKeyboardType = SoftKeyboardType.DEFAULT
secondfield.stage = example.stage
secondfield.viewPort = new Rectangle(example.x, example.y, example.width, example.height);
```

Comment: That should work (assuming you are using addChild for both). Try setting the x and y literally so you're sure you are not overlaying one over the other and set the stage as the same stage for both.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you please show me an example? Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var firstfield:StageText = new StageText(); 
firstfield.softKeyboardType = SoftKeyboardType.DEFAULT
firstfield.stage = this.stage;
firstfield.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 30);
firstfield.x = 0;
firstfield.y = 0;
firstfield.width = 200;
firstfield.height = 30;
addChild(firstfield); 

var secondfield:StageText = new StageText(); 
secondfield.softKeyboardType = SoftKeyboardType.DEFAULT
secondfield.stage = this.stage;
secondfield.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 40, 200, 30);
secondfield.x = 0;
secondfield.y = 40;
secondfield.width = 200;
secondfield.height = 30;
addChild(secondfield);
```

Comment: I'm sorry but, how is this answer correct?, the StageText class doesn't even has x, y, width or height properties. This answer is completely wrong.